# printf не отображет конкретное значение

Tags: c, форматирование, printf

При выведении результатов некорректно отображаются значения(вместо 0,33333... выводит 0,0000...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>


int main(void){

    float f_number = 1.0/3.0;
    double d_number = 1.0/3.0;

    printf("#1f %.4f \n");
    printf("#2f %.12f \n");
    printf("#3f %.16f \n");
    printf("#1d %.4lf \n");
    printf("#2d %.12lf \n");
    printf("#3d %.16lf \n");
    printf("max float accuracy %d \n", FLT_DIG);
    printf("max double accuracy %d \n", DBL_DIG);

    return 0;
}
```

Где я неправ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("#1f %.4f \n", f_number);
```

и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо, на сегодня пора кончать с программированием))

Comment: @РусланМамедов Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: через 7 минут отмечу